# Give weight to document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of documents like below:

```
[{'term': 'iphone', 'frequency': 10},
{'term': 'ipad', 'frequency': 100}]
```

I would like to boost the score of the search results using the `frequency` value of the document.

If a user writes `'ip'` for example I would like `ipad` to go on top of the search results since it has a higher `frequency` value than `iphone`.

Is this achievable somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using `function_score` and `field_value_factor`:

```
{'query': {
    'function_score': {
        'query': {
            'prefix': {
                'term': {
                    'value': 'ip'
                }
            }
        },
        'field_value_factor': {
            'field': 'frequency'
        }
    }
}
```